# SonarQube Azure AD login does not place users in correct groups

Tags: sonarqube, azure-active-directory, usergroups

I have set up Azure AD authentication on my SonarQube server as well as the corresponding app registration listed in Azure AD. The problem I am facing is that when I try to authenticate to the SonarQube portal using my Azure login, it logs me into the portal but doesn't place my account in the correct group!

My account is placed in the "sonar-users" default group when it should be fed into the other group which is named exactly the same as the group listed in Azure AD (as per the SQ documentation).

Has any one experienced any issues similar to this? If so, did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked, that your APP-registration has the corresponding permissions to the AAD?

Sign in and read user profile
Read all users' basic profiles
Read directory data

https://github.com/hkamel/sonar-auth-aad Point 7